# How to render html for variables in Flask render_template

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask render_template method to render my html page as below:

`render_template('index.html', content="<div>Hello World!</div>")`

My index.html is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
{{content}}
</body>
</html>
```

My page is replacing the content variable, but it is rendering `<div>Hello World!</div>` as text.

Is there a way to render html from render_template context variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flask turns on Jinja's autoescape feature. Quoting the [manual](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#controlling-autoescaping) on how to disable it:

There are three ways to accomplish that:

1. In the Python code, wrap the HTML string in a Markup object before passing it to the template. This is in general the recommended way.
2. Inside the template, use the `|safe` filter to explicitly mark a string as safe HTML (`{{ myvariable|safe }}`)`
3. Temporarily disable the autoescape system altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require passing in `HTML` tags into the template, you may simply do something that looks like this

---

### Template

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div> 
        {{content}}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### Python code

```py
@app.route('/')
def home():
    render_template('index.html', content="Hello World!")
```

This should be perfectly fine. If you do want to add html into your `content` variable, then the answer by @Ture Pålsson is the best way forward.

Comment: If at all possible, this is probably a better approach than the one I suggested. It's a good idea to keep the HTML in the templates and out of the Python code!